# ACCEPT statement in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am a beginner in PL SQL.

I'm trying to accept a string in a variable using the PL SQL ACCEPT statement.
Here is the code -

```
ACCEPT lastname CHAR FORMAT 'A20' PROMPT 'Enter employee lastname:  '
DECLARE
BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lastname);  
END;
```

I'm not getting any error or output in SQL Developer. I am not able to understand what am I missing here.

Basically, what I am trying to do is read a value (String) from a user and use that in my queries against a table.

Comment: You must be getting an invalid-identifier error...

Comment: Nope. No error whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ACCEPT is a [SQL*Plus and SQL Developer client command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm), not a PL/SQL command. You are setting a substitution variable, which you could [use](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) in an anonymous block with:

```
ACCEPT lastname CHAR FORMAT 'A20' PROMPT 'Enter employee lastname:  '

SET serveroutput on;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('&lastname');  
END;
/
```

It would be more common to use it in SQL though:

```
select '&lastname' from dual;
```

PL/SQL isn't designed to be used interactively, but it isn't clear what you will really be doing.

---

SQL Developer (version 4.1.3, at least) doesn't seem to handle `format` quite the same as SQL*Plus, which may be a bug. If you use ACCEPT as shown in the question and the code above there is no prompt or output from the script; the logging pane shows a 'severe' message from Accept.java:341. It does work if you also supply a default:

```
ACCEPT lastname CHAR FORMAT 'A20' DEFAULT 'dummy' PROMPT 'Enter employee lastname:  '
```

The default value is not shown in the prompt dialog box, and your substitution variable will contain that default value if you just OK the dialog - which is the expected behaviour "if a reply is not given". If you don't want a default you're a bit stuck though - specifying a null default (with `''`) also gets the same severe message, which may be related.

Comment: Why am I not able to see anything when I execute your above code in my SQL Developer? What I am trying to do is capture the input from the user in a variable which will then be used in my where clause of the SQL statement.

Comment: I don"t know. Are you running as a script or as a statement? You need script for this. Are you sure you have an active connection?

Comment: Tried running it as a script and as a statement. Oracle SQL Developer just says that "Task completed in ... secs" but nothing happens. I am pretty sure I have an active connection. Just edited the question above. (last line)

Comment: I tried removing the **FORMAT 'A20'** and it ran successfully. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, that's a difference in behaviour between SQL\*Plus (which allows the format) and SQL Developer; odd that it stop it responding at all - suspect that's a bug rather than intentional. The logging page shows a reference to validateDefaultAndFormat(Accept.java:341). Oddly it does work if you also supply a default value.