# PLSQL dbms_output.put_line() is not working while taking input from user

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

In my PL/SQL code I have to print some line on the console and then I have to take the choice from the user but in my case it never print anything on the console and directly wait for the user input.

Here is my code:

```
declare
cust_id Customer.cust_id%type;
cust_name Customer.name%type;
cust_purchase Customer.total_purchase%type;
cust_category varchar2(30);
input int := 1;

cursor cursor_customer is select * from Customer;

begin

dbms_output.put_line('Which one you want to use?');
dbms_output.put_line('1. PROCEDURE');
dbms_output.put_line('2. FUNCTION');

input := &t;

open cursor_customer;
loop
fetch cursor_customer into cust_id, cust_name, cust_purchase;
    exit when cursor_customer%notfound;
    if (input = 1) then
        proc_grade(cust_id,cust_name,cust_purchase,cust_category);
    elsif (input = 2) then
        cust_category := func_grade(cust_id,cust_name,cust_purchase);
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('Category is added for the client id '|| cust_id || ' is ' || cust_category);

end loop;

close cursor_customer;

end;
/
```

In **begin** I have written three dbms_output.put_line() statements but this statements are not executing it directly waiting for the user input.

**Here is the output after running the code**

Enter value for t:

But when I remove the statement which is taking the input "**input := &t;**" then the all the output statements are worked.

Please anyone could tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't. PL/SQL is  mostly standardised for database interactions and  not designed for interactive user input / output. Use a wrapper language/ script on top like bash, python, windows batch etc for such requirements.

Comment: Does your assignment actually say you have to 'print some line on the console' from PL/SQL; and is it safe to assume this only has to run in SQL\*Plus? You've tagged the question with that and with PL/SQL Developer - but as you're using substitution variables did you really mean that, or SQL Developer? You might really want something [more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35441894/266304)? Depends what your exact task is though, and what you've been taught...

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the result of DBMS_OUTPUT until the whole procedure has finished; it isn't "interactive" as you thought.

Therefore, ask use what they want to do **before** calling the PL/SQL procedure and pass the choice as a parameter.

---

`acc.sql` file:

```
accept par_deptno number prompt "Enter department number: "

set serveroutput on
set ver off
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from emp 
    where deptno = &par_deptno;

  dbms_output.put_line('There are ' || l_cnt || ' employees in that department');
end;
/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> @acc
Enter department number: 10
There are 3 employees in that department

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: So you mean I have to convert this plsql block as a procedure and then I have to take input in another block and pass it to the procedure.
Correct?

Comment: That would be one option. Another is to put everything into a .SQL file (use `accept` to acquire parameter's value) and call it from SQL*Plus command prompt. I've modified my answer to show you how to do that; have a look.

Comment: I have already tried, what you have written in your answer. But by using accept where I have to write the three dbms_output line?
If I write before the accept then it is giving me an error.

Comment: You'd use PROMPT instead.